# Entity Framework code first reverse engineer identity column inset

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EntityFramework as my ORM. I've created my code models using reverse engineer, and moved the generated domain objects to my core layer.

When I try to create a new entity that in the database has identity column with identity increment, and do SaveChanges() - it fails. I used profiler to see what's being sent to the database and I see that it tries to insert the identity column with zero as a value (since it's an integer it's automatically assigned zero as value).

How can I tell Entity Framework mapping to ignore this field at insert? (I don't want to do this at the domain object - I rather keep domain object as plain as possible without specific annotations)

**Edit**

It appears to be because of an inheritance I've done. I've created an object that inherits from the object I'm trying to insert - but I don't see why that would bother it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Key` attribute on it or pass in  `DatabaseGenerationOption.Computed` to the `DatabaseGenerated` key

Comment: tried it. It doesn't work in case the object is being inherited from.

Comment: You mean the ID field is inherited from another class?

Comment: no. the object I'm having trouble with is being inherited from. it's my Member object (and have few member details) and than I have MemberFullDetails object that inherits from Member.

Comment: Those attributes should work on the base class.  I think they are automatically inherited too